# Excel read-only popup occurs after save as script c#

Tags: c#, excel

My below code opens, deletes the first row in excel and then saves the file as a CSV.

However when the next user wishes to open the CSV they are presented with the screen shot below;

[image]

Can anyone advise how I would remove this from happening and the pop-up will not happen when the user next enters the file. (Enabling Editing).

I have figured it could be a setting when I am saving the file down however I cannot see anything to resolve this out after extensive stack overflow & Code project searching.

```
        public void DeleteRows(string OriginalFileName,String NewFileName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet myWorkSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;
        myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        myWorkBook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(OriginalFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        myWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)myWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)myWorkSheet.Application.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
        range.Select();
        range.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
        myApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        myWorkSheet.SaveAs(NewFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, false, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        myWorkBook.Close(false);
        myApp.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you legend! Been looking at this for ages!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-saveas-method-excel), the `true` in:

```
myWorkSheet.SaveAs(NewFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, true, (etc etc)
```

means:

> ReadOnlyRecommended   - True to display a message when the file is
>   opened, recommending that the file be opened as read-only.

I suspect you want that value to be `false`.